# fluent nhibernate component one-to-many

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

I have couple of classes and want to map them correctly to database:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual ComponentClass Component { get; set; }
}

public class ComponentClass 
{
    public virtual IList<B> Elements { get;set; }
}

public class B
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual DateTime Time { get; set; }
}
```

I map them using fluent mappings like that:

```
public class AMap : ClassMap<A> 
{
    public A() {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Component(x => x.Component,
                  c => c.HasMany(x => x.Elements).Inverse().Cascade.All());
    }
}

public class BMap : ClassMap<B>
{
    public B() {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Time);
    }
}
```

When I save my entity, I have class A mapped to one table and class B to another as expected.
But I have nulls in Component_id column.
Can you tell me what am I missing here?

Comment: Ok, I've resolved my problem - I can use Id of my "parent" class. So the component mapping will become: c.HasMany(x => x.Elements).Cascade.All().Column("Id");

Answer (score 1):

I believe Components are supposed to be in the same table , as clearly stated in [Ayende's blog post](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/08/nhibernate-mapping-ltcomponentgt.aspx), as they serve only to make the data better represented as an object model.  Be sure to read through his blog, it's probably one of the best nHibernate resources out there.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've resolved my problem - I can use Id of my "parent" class. So the component mapping will become:

```
public class AMap : ClassMap<A> 
{
    public A() {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Component(x => x.Component,
                  c => c.HasMany(x => x.Elements).Cascade.All().Column("Id"));
    }
}
```

So obvious as I look at it now ... but It took me an hour.

Comment: This will only give you a one-to-one relationship as you are explicitly mapping the component to it's parent via the same Id value, i.e. `Parent.1 => Component.1, Parent.2 => Component.2`

Comment: Also, you no longer have a value object, you now have an entity that inherits parent's identity.  If you have entity.Id = 1, and entity.Id = 2, and both have a value object that has same value, each component is supposed to be interchangeable by definition, but no longer is - you now have Component.1 and Component.2.  It is possible to map a Component collection "correctly", but NHibernate does not allow sharing components i.e no one-to-many or a component that contains a collection such as you have defined here.  See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/components.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have a one-to-many association direct to a collection of components (ie. without the `ComponentClass` wrapper as per the question) then you can map it directly:

```
HasMany(x => x.Elements)
    .AsSet()
    .Table("ElementTable")
    .KeyColumn("KeyColumn")
    .Cascade.All()
    .Component(x =>
    {
        x.Map(c => c.Id);
        x.Map(c => c.Time);
    })
    .LazyLoad();
```